# Java web project not running after cleaning?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I clicked on `Project` > `Clean...` in Eclipse Kepler, removed the project from the local Tomcat7 server list and re-added it. Now when I attempt to run the website I get a 404 error.
I have attempted restarting the Tomcat server and restarting Eclipse to no avail.

How do I correctly re-run my web project after cleaning so it loads in the browser?

edit: Just to clarify the web project was working perfectly fine before Cleaning.

I browse to the web project like so: `http://localhost:8080/website/`

Comment: Restarting eclipse/tomcat won't do anything if your mappings aren't properly set up. What URL are you trying to reach and where is it handled by your web app?

Comment: when you open up the console view are you seeing a stack trace? Also in your browser have you tried localhost:8080/project_name? Have you tried right clicking the project name and doing debug or run as server?

Comment: If there isn't a stack trace in the console view then I would go deeper and goto your tomcat installation and check the log files. If that turns up with nothing I would check your deployment assembly and build paths to make sure nothing magically changed itself

Comment: Does cleaning do something to the settings of a web project that I'd need to redo after woulds?

Comment: Cleaning will remove all the compiled resources. You have to rebuild it, which you can do manually by right click the project and select Build or if you have the Automatic Build option enabled just change a file to recompile the project.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I had removed some external jar files from the project before clean and not removed them from the Build path list. Once I removed them form the build path list the Project Built fine again.